# what is the use of custom-artifact in spinnaker, it always gives error - Custom references are passed on to cloud platforms to handle or process 500

Tags: spinnaker

i am trying to use custom-artifact account in spinnaker.

I have a pipeline, where i want to pull a http file (a deployment manifest) as an artifact, and use it in deployment.

i use custom-artifact and put the url - (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdputurn/flask-k8s-inspector/master/Deployment.yaml) in reference.

I have tried running this pipeline multiple times, but i always fails with the error (Internal Server Error",“message”:“Custom references are passed on to cloud platforms to handle or process”,“status”:500)

i saw some tutorials where they just use custom artifact and put some http url to get files for deploy stage.

steps to re-produce:
1. create a new pipeline --> in configuration stage --> add artifact --> choose "custom-artifact" --> update reference with (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdputurn/flask-k8s-inspector/master/Deployment.yaml) --> check "use default artifact" and fill the same details -- > add one more stage Deploy --> use the artifact template from configuration stage --> run the pipeline

spinnaker version - 1.16.1

Comment: i just upgraded spinnaker to 1.16.4 and could see the error of same use case is - Artifact credentials 'custom-artifact' cannot handle artifacts of type 'http/file'

Answer (score 0):

For the Spinnaker version 1.17.1 the custom-artifact is deprecated. If possible use the embedded-artifact>produce an artifact and use the artifact in another execution.